# using fax4j in maven java project on windows 7

Tags: java, maven

I'm using fax4j in maven java project on windows 7.

I have a little code to send a fax. When run code the program responds follow error:

> Error Code: 258 Message: Unable to send fax.

My pom.xml project just have one dependency:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.fax4j</groupId>
<artifactId>fax4j</artifactId>
<version>0.42.9</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my project just have one class main like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.fax4j.FaxClient;
import org.fax4j.FaxClientFactory;
import org.fax4j.FaxJob;
import org.fax4j.FaxJob.FaxJobPriority;
import org.fax4j.FaxJobStatus;
public class FaxTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FaxClient faxClient = FaxClientFactory.createFaxClient();

    FaxJob faxJob = faxClient.createFaxJob();

    File file = getFile("fax/fax.txt");
    if (file == null) {
        System.err.println("ERRO fax.txt.");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("OK fax.txt.");
    }
    faxJob.setFile(file);
    faxJob.setPriority(FaxJobPriority.HIGH_PRIORITY);
    faxJob.setTargetAddress("0222088888");
    faxJob.setTargetName("ANO piso 1");
    faxJob.setSenderEmail("xxx@gmail.com");
    faxJob.setSenderFaxNumber("0222088889");
    faxJob.setSenderName("xxx");

    //Once the fax job contains all the needed info, you submit it via fax client:
    //submit fax job
    faxClient.submitFaxJob(faxJob);
    System.out.println("Fax Job Sumbitted: " + faxJob.getID());

    while (faxClient.getFaxJobStatus(faxJob) == FaxJobStatus.PENDING) {
        System.out.println("STATUS: "
                + faxClient.getFaxJobStatus(faxJob).toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error sleep: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("FINAL STATUS: "
            + faxClient.getFaxJobStatus(faxJob).toString());
}

/**
 * getFile pass argument pathFile
 *
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 */
private static File
        getFile(String fileName) {
    //Get file from resources folder
    ClassLoader classLoader = FaxTest.class
            .getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    return file;
}
}
```

now(23(04/2015), the output log is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building faxTeste 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
=== PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
Project:       pt.ano:faxTeste:1.0-SNAPSHOT
Dependencies (collect): []
Dependencies (resolve): [test]
Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli)
Style:         Regular
Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">${exec.classpathScope}</classpathScope>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <executable>${exec.executable}</executable>
  <longClasspath default-value="false">${exec.longClasspath}</longClasspath>
  <outputFile>${exec.outputFile}</outputFile>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
  <workingDirectory>${exec.workingdir}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
=======================================================================
pt.ano:faxTeste:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
   net.sf.fax4j:fax4j:jar:0.42.9:compile
      javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
         javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
      commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
         commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
      commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
      org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
      net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-core:jar:1.0.3:compile
      net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-inet-ftp:jar:1.0.3:compile
      net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-utils:jar:1.0.3:compile
         log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
         commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
            commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:1.0:compile
               junit:junit:jar:3.7:compile
         urbanophile:java-getopt:jar:1.0.9:compile
      net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-pool:jar:1.0.3:compile
         concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
      org.rxtx:rxtx:jar:2.1.7:compile

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ faxTeste ---
Created new class realm maven.api
Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.project < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.model < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < maven.ext
Populating class realm maven.api
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1:
   org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
         org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
      commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
      classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
      junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:test (scope managed from compile) (version managed from 3.8.1)
   org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
  Imported:  < maven.api
Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
  Included: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1
  Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
  Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
  Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9
  Excluded: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1497b7b1]
Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec' with basic configurator -->
  (f) basedir = C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste
  (f) classpathScope = runtime
  (f) commandlineArgs = -classpath %classpath pt.ano.faxteste.FaxTest
  (f) executable = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
  (f) longClasspath = false
  (f) project = MavenProject: pt.ano:faxTeste:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste\pom.xml
  (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@4e6cf5e8
  (f) skip = false
-- end configuration --
Collected project artifacts [net.sf.fax4j:fax4j:jar:0.42.9:compile, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile, net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-core:jar:1.0.3:compile, net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-inet-ftp:jar:1.0.3:compile, net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-utils:jar:1.0.3:compile, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:1.0:compile, junit:junit:jar:3.7:compile, urbanophile:java-getopt:jar:1.0.9:compile, net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-pool:jar:1.0.3:compile, concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile, org.rxtx:rxtx:jar:2.1.7:compile]
Collected project classpath [C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste\target\classes]
dealing with net.sf.fax4j:fax4j:jar:0.42.9:compile
dealing with javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
dealing with javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
dealing with commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
dealing with commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
dealing with commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
dealing with org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
dealing with net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-core:jar:1.0.3:compile
dealing with net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-inet-ftp:jar:1.0.3:compile
dealing with net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-utils:jar:1.0.3:compile
dealing with log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
dealing with commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
dealing with commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:1.0:compile
dealing with junit:junit:jar:3.7:compile
dealing with urbanophile:java-getopt:jar:1.0.9:compile
dealing with net.sf.gnu-hylafax:gnu-hylafax-pool:jar:1.0.3:compile
dealing with concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
dealing with org.rxtx:rxtx:jar:2.1.7:compile
Toolchains are ignored, 'executable' parameter is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
Executing command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste\target\classes;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\net\sf\fax4j\fax4j\0.42.9\fax4j-0.42.9.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.7\mail-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.2\commons-codec-1.2.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\net\sf\gnu-hylafax\gnu-hylafax-core\1.0.3\gnu-hylafax-core-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\net\sf\gnu-hylafax\gnu-hylafax-inet-ftp\1.0.3\gnu-hylafax-inet-ftp-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\net\sf\gnu-hylafax\gnu-hylafax-utils\1.0.3\gnu-hylafax-utils-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\1.0\commons-lang-1.0.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.7\junit-3.7.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\urbanophile\java-getopt\1.0.9\java-getopt-1.0.9.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\net\sf\gnu-hylafax\gnu-hylafax-pool\1.0.3\gnu-hylafax-pool-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\concurrent\concurrent\1.3.4\concurrent-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\nuno_marinho\.m2\repository\org\rxtx\rxtx\2.1.7\rxtx-2.1.7.jar pt.ano.faxteste.FaxTest
OK fax.txt.
READ file fax.txt:
Teste Nuno Marinho
Exception in thread "main" org.fax4j.FaxException: Error while invoking fax action process, exit code: -1073740940 process output:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Debug mode enabled.
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Checking argument:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] -action
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Argument value:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] submit
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Checking argument:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] -target_address
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Argument value:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] 132
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Checking argument:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] -target_name
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Argument value:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] ANO
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Checking argument:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] -sender_name
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Argument value:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Nuno Marinho
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Checking argument:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] -file
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Argument value:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste\target\classes\fax\fax.txt
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Read input:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Action:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] submit
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Server:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] (null)
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Fax Job ID:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] (null)
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Target Address:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] 132
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Target Name:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] ANO
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Sender Name:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Nuno Marinho
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] File:
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] C:\Projectos\GSPGSEMDD\faxTeste\target\classes\fax\fax.txt
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Handling specific fax action.
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Invoking submitFaxJobNative
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Connecting to fax server.
[fax4j-native][DEBUG] Initializing fax job parameters.

process error:

    at org.fax4j.spi.process.ExitCodeProcessOutputValidator.validateProcessOutput(ExitCodeProcessOutputValidator.java:42)
    at org.fax4j.spi.windows.WindowsProcessOutputValidator.validateProcessOutput(WindowsProcessOutputValidator.java:42)
    at org.fax4j.spi.process.ProcessFaxClientSpi.validateProcessOutput(ProcessFaxClientSpi.java:566)
    at org.fax4j.spi.process.ProcessFaxClientSpi.executeProcess(ProcessFaxClientSpi.java:492)
    at org.fax4j.spi.process.ProcessFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJobImpl(ProcessFaxClientSpi.java:351)
    at org.fax4j.spi.AbstractFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJob(AbstractFaxClientSpi.java:308)
    at org.fax4j.spi.adapter.AbstractAdapterFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJobImpl(AbstractAdapterFaxClientSpi.java:94)
    at org.fax4j.spi.AbstractFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJob(AbstractFaxClientSpi.java:308)
    at org.fax4j.spi.adapter.AbstractAdapterFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJobImpl(AbstractAdapterFaxClientSpi.java:94)
    at org.fax4j.spi.AbstractFaxClientSpi.submitFaxJob(AbstractFaxClientSpi.java:308)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.fax4j.spi.AbstractFaxClientSpiProxy.invoke(AbstractFaxClientSpiProxy.java:203)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.submitFaxJob(Unknown Source)
    at org.fax4j.FaxClient.submitFaxJob(FaxClient.java:214)
    at pt.ano.faxteste.FaxTest.main(FaxTest.java:57)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 18.282s
Finished at: Thu Apr 23 10:55:01 BST 2015
Final Memory: 5M/122M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project faxTeste: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project faxTeste: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more


For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

Comment: You might want to consider pasting your output log.

Comment: Error Code: 258 Message: Unable to send fax. need more?

Comment: Not just the error, the output from the library before the error. (disclaimer I've never used it, but thought that might be helpful after seeing some longer logs in Google)

Comment: see the output log please :D

Comment: Maybe the phone numbers are bad? I wonder if numbers starting with 02 are valid - maybe it needs to be internationalized (e.g. +1 for US)?

Comment: not . now the problem is in "Initializing fax job parameters." not in send.

Comment: Right - that's why I said what I did. You are calling 'faxJob.setTargetAddress("0222088888");' Maybe the target address isn't valid.

Comment: yes but this number is fake. just a example :D

Comment: Just suggesting that you make sure the format of those is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine. I know because i created a maven project with your code in my PC with windows 7 and all works fine :D