# fax4j in maven java project on w7 - detect received fax

Tags: java, maven, fax

I create a project like this [using fax4j in maven java project on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29804272/3703397) .

Now i neee implements one system that detect received fax any idea?

I use maven java project with fax4j in w7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fax4j api is only prepared to send faxs . this api not supports fax reception.